# Why do I get error 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

```
class MyClassification:
    def __init__(self, lst2, search):
        self.lst2 = lst2
        self.search = search

    def search(self):
        if self.search in self.lst2:
            return True
        else:
            return False


var = MyClassification([1, 2, 3, 'Alex'], 'peter')
print(var.search())
```

I want to search if a name exists in a list or not but I get `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` when I run `print(var.search())`.

Comment: Hi, please provide an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You have both a method and a non-method attribute called `search`, and the assignment in the initializer is overwriting the method. You need to rename either the method or `self.search = search`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that you used search as a parameter name and also as a method name, you should avoid naming both the same.